# Getting error on file name

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

Hi everyone i am finding difficulty in accessing the file from my project assets folder.
This is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="androidhive.info.materialdesign.activity.HomeFragment"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">


<!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/label"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->
    <!--android:textSize="30sp"-->
    <!--android:text="About PES"-->
    <!--android:textStyle="bold"/>-->

<!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:layout_below="@id/label"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp"-->
    <!--android:textColor="@color/text"-->
    <!--android:text="@string/aboutpes"-->
    <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
    <!--android:textIsSelectable="true" />-->
<WebView android:id="@+id/webPage"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

This my fragment file

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
private WebView webView;
public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webPage);
    //  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/programs.html");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}


public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
   super.onAttach(activity);
}


public void onDetach() {
   super.onDetach();
}
```

}

Would be grateful if somebody suggests me where i am going wrong. So that i can correct myself.

Comment: what problem u are getting ? also make sure added INTERNET Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: ya i have added the INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest file.. The error i am getting is webpage not available

Comment: ok try to use `android_asset` instead of `android_assets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webPage);
webView .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
  @Override  
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
  {  
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
  }  
}); 
webView .loadUrl("file:///android_assets/programs.html");
```

Comment: Hi Neal still it display's the same error - the web page not available

Comment: check your folder name, is it "assets" or "asset" ...?